# How can I tell if a piece of traffic is Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I am trying to get my meta tags right for certain pages, and in order to do that I need to trick facebook into reading a different header.

How can I detect if user is infact Facebook's spider/crawler on the prowl for meta tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable tells you that. It's usually something like this `facebookexternalhit/1.0 ( http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` if it is facebook reading your site